# Resolving nodejs circular dependancies

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binance

I know this question has been asked several times but I cant solve it in my project structure.

I have 3 files:

1. `new_order.js`
2. `binance.js`
3. `advance.js`

`new_order.js` is responsible for initializing values and passing it to `binance.js` to execute an order.

`binance.js` then executes a the order and has a websocket running at all times to wait for the event where the order is filled. Because I can't return values in websockets, I call `advance.js` right after the order has been filled.

`advance.js` has advance functions like having a stoploss/take profit. The problem I am having is, once the price reaches the stoploss/take profit level, I have to call `binance.js` again to execute a sell order.

My flow is `new_order.js` -> `binance.js` <-> `advance.js` .. how can I overcome this issue, and also is it possible to return a value from `binance.js` back to `new_order.js` from a fulltime running websocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file index.js and import everything there in order. Then in all rest of files import from index.js.

```
// index.js
import * from "new_order"
import * from "binance.js"
import * from "advance.js"

// binance.js
import {func_from_advance} from "index.js"

// advance.js
import {func_from_binance} from "index.js"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: Is it possible to use native imports in nodejs?

Comment: Basic idea is to import from all files in index.js and then import from index.js in other files.